# Flex-wrap doesn't seem to be working, images are displayed in a column instead

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am relatively new to Web D and I wanted 4 images to be displayed on a single row, and the other 4 to be in another row, below. (Note: I added `display: flex;` and `flex-: wrap;` but it didn't work.) The images are displayed in a single column, instead of 2 separate rows. Also, is it possible to have these 8 images to fit the entire width of the browser? The code which I used, is displayed below. Thank you in advance! :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Gallery */

.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/1.jpg">Image1</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/2.jpg">Image2</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/3.jpg">Image3</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/4.jpg">Image4</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/5.jpg">Image5</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/6.jpg">Image6</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/7.jpg">Image7</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="Images/8.jpg">Image8</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works fine when you take all the `>` characters away from your CSS.

Comment: Is it possible to have the images displayed in two different rows? 4 images at the top and 4 images at the bottom. I also want it to fit the entire width of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have a image width, look at the `.flex-item > img` class, where we tell the image to be 100% of it's parent.

Regarding having it in one row I would go with a media query to support that. My guess is that you want 8 on larger screens?

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  .flex-item {
    flex-basis: calc(100 / 8);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Gallery */

.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}

.flex-item>img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image1</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image2</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image3</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image4</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image5</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image6</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image7</div>
    <div class="flex-item"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">Image8</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it should work well for you:

HTML:
[image]

And here is the appropriate CSS:

[image]

You can adjust the images to what ever size you want and it should work.

Let me know if that helps.